# Localstack - Access SNS via java aws sdk : NoSuchFieldError: ENDPOINT_OVERRIDDEN

Tags: java, aws-java-sdk, localstack

I am playing around with a localstack instance running on docker. I try to access the sns service, but receiving a error while executing methods like "listTopics()" or "createTopic()"
I didnt find any help on Google yet, so may anyone has a idea whats wrong here ?

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ENDPOINT_OVERRIDDEN
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.executeListTopics(AmazonSNSClient.java:1830) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.875.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.listTopics(AmazonSNSClient.java:1812) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.875.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.listTopics(AmazonSNSClient.java:1853) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.875.jar:na]
    at com.example.dockerspringboot.DockerSpringBootApplication.getSnsClient(DockerSpringBootApplication.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.dockerspringboot.DockerSpringBootApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a65fee3d.CGLIB$getSnsClient$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.dockerspringboot.DockerSpringBootApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a65fee3d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$99ad7dfd.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.example.dockerspringboot.DockerSpringBootApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a65fee3d.getSnsClient(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

I try to access the localstack sns service via the java aws sdk:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.875</version>
</dependency>
```

The Code in my App where the error is thrown looks like this:

```
private String serviceEndpoint = "http://localhost:4566";
private String signingRegion = "eu-west-1";

@Bean
    public AmazonSNS getSnsClient() {
        AmazonSNS sns = AmazonSNSClient.builder().withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(serviceEndpoint, signingRegion)).withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()).build();

        System.out.println(sns.listTopics().toString());

        return sns;
    }
```

I am running localstack on Docker with this docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "localstack"
    image: localstack/localstack-full
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "4566-4599:4566-4599"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,sns
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock

    volumes:
      - "local_vol:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
volumes:
  local_vol:
      driver: local
```

Creating a SNS topic via cmdline works fine, so the service is running!

```
/opt/code/localstack # aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sns create-topic --name my_topic
{
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:my_topic"
}
/opt/code/localstack # aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sns list-topics
{
    "Topics": [
        {
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:my_topic"
        }
    ]
}
```

btw.: I do also use the S3 of localstock, this one is working - may those 2 conflict in anyway ?

Hope someone could help me, fix this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone run into this,
i couldnt find the actual problem here, but got it working with the amazon aws sdk for java 2.0 .

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sns</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

I've also encountered this error for using the AmazonRoute53Client.

Upon checking, there's no ENDPOINT_OVERRIDDEN field on the HandlerContextKey class.

This class can be found on the aws-java-sdk-core library. The ENDPOINT_OVERRIDDEN was added starting on 1.11.873.

**Solution:**
Update the aws-java-sdk-core to latest or at least 1.11.873

[Github source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/handlers/HandlerContextKey.java)

[Library: aws-java-sdk-core for version 1.11.873](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.873)

Comment: You can say the same thing for the aws subdependencies as well. Upgraded SES to this version and the ENDPOINT_OVERRIDDEN error was removed! 
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.930</version>

Answer (score 4):

Recently I encountered the above issue, and it was not because of `LocalStack` or any AWS local development docker image. This issue is related to the version mismatch of `com.amazonaws` group dependencies with AWS core module. This issue arises of the classpath AWS SDK dependencies don't match with the version of the AWS core module. To avoid this version conflict `aws-java-sdk-bom` should be used, and the BOM module will take care of the versioning problems.

**Code Snippet**

Let say if the latest version of `aws-java-sdk-bom` is `1.11.934` [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bom)

- Maven

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.934</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

- Gradle

```
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns'
    }
    
    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.934'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also run into the same problem.

The error comes from using 2 different AWS libraries that each depend on a different AWS SDK core versions.

We need to make sure that version numbers are consistent. They are releasing updated versions every couple of days: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/releases

The recommended way to use AWS dependencies with Maven is to use BOM that will synchronize AWS dependency versions. More information:https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/managing-dependencies-with-aws-sdk-for-java-bill-of-materials-module-bom/